# MySQL AND vs OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I am trying to get a collection from a main table that meets the condition of a child table. what I am trying is this:

```
SELECT main_table.* 
FROM main_table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_available ON main_table.id = category_available.main_table_id 
WHERE  category_available.category_id = 206 AND category_available.category_id = 207;
```

I get no results even though the main table contains a row that has entries that meet both the AND conditions from the child table. If I substitute the AND for an OR I get expected results, but the query needs to meet the AND condition.

category_available is a child table. It contains many rows that can be tied to a single main table row. So it might contain two rows that contain the main_table id, one with an id of 206 and another with 207. So i need to return the main_table row(s) that meet both conditions.

Comment: How can something be equal to both 206 and 207 at the same time?

Comment: Why do you think the query needs to meet the and condition?

Comment: Is there a many-to-one relationship with the `main_table.id` to the `category_available` table?  Is there a foreign key relationship set up as many-to-one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group the records by the PK of your `main_table` and then filter the corresponding groups accordingly:

```
SELECT   m.* 
FROM     main_table m JOIN category_available c ON c.main_table_id = m.id
WHERE    c.category_id IN (206, 207)
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT c.category_id) = 2
```

If the `category_available` table guarantees the uniqueness of `(main_table_id, category_id)`, you can avoid the costly `DISTINCT` operation by using `COUNT(*) = 2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or is what you want...the 'and' condition here is never true

```
category_available.category_id = 206 AND category_available.category_id = 207
```

This statement can be reduced to where 206 = 207, which is never true and never return results.  How can one field equal 206 and 207 at the same time?

Edit:

This is probably closer to what you are looking for...there are a couple ways of writing this, if it was a one time run script, I'd approach it with a count:

eggyal beat me to it...my script was a mirror of what he posted a few mins ago.

Comment: category_available is a child table. It contains many rows that can be tied to a single main table row. So it might contain two rows that contain the main_table id, one with an id of 206 and another with 207. So i need to return the main_table row(s) that meet both conditions.

Comment: @sudopratt Clarify that in your question

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  When you join a single row to two rows, you get two rows...in this case one with 206 and one with 207.  Since neither has both, neither are returned.  Clarify in your question and let me edit the answer

Comment: @Twelfth I added that info to the question.